# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into even if I'm not inserting that column

Tags: sql, oracle

I get this error: `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("GRT2158A"."BUVETTE"."NUMB")`.

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO Buvette(Emplacement, NumS)
SELECT Emplacement, NumS
FROM GILLES_HUBERT.tp4_buvettes;
```

**What I do understand:** NUMB is a primary key with a constraint to check if it's not null. Then, I cannot insert NULL there.

**What I don't understand:** I'm not even inserting the NUMB column, just *Emplacement* and *NumS*. Why does it complain about NUMB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not providing any value for a column then that column's value will be created with its default value and, if you have not specified a default, then `NULL` will be inserted.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE Buvette(
  NumB        NUMBER CONSTRAINT Buvette__Numb__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Emplacement NUMBER,
  NumS        NUMBER DEFAULT 4
);

INSERT INTO (Emplacement) VALUES ( 1 );
```

is the equivalent of doing:

```
INSERT INTO (NumB, Emplacement, NumS) VALUES ( NULL, 1, 4 );
```

Where `NumB` has no default so `NULL` is inserted but `NumS` has a default of 4 so 4 is inserted.

**In Oracle 12c**, you can now specify a sequence as the default:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Buvette__NumB__Seq;

CREATE TABLE Buvette(
  NumB        NUMBER DEFAULT Buvette__NumB__Seq.NEXTVAL
                     CONSTRAINT Buvette__Numb__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Emplacement NUMBER,
  NumS        NUMBER DEFAULT 4
);
```

or you can use an `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE Buvette(
  NumB        NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 )
                     CONSTRAINT Buvette__Numb__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Emplacement NUMBER,
  NumS        NUMBER DEFAULT 4
);
```

Then you can just use your statement and the default value for `NumB` will be generated:

```
INSERT INTO Buvette(Emplacement, NumS)
SELECT Emplacement, NumS
FROM GILLES_HUBERT.tp4_buvettes;
```

**In earlier versions**, you will want to use the sequence in the `INSERT` statement to generate an incrementing primary key:

```
INSERT INTO Buvette ( NumB, Eplacement, NumS )
SELECT Buvette__NumB__Seq.NEXTVAL,
       Emplacement,
       NumS
FROM   GILLES_HUBERT.tp4_buvettes;
```

Answer (score 0):

But you *are* inserting `NULL` -- or at least the default value.  You don't include it in the columns getting a value, so it needs to get some value.  Apparently, there is no default.

In Oracle, this would generally mean that a trigger is not assigned to the table.  You'll need to learn how to insert a unique value into the column.  This is often handled through a sequence:

```
INSERT INTO Buvette(NumB, Emplacement, NumS)
    SELECT buvette_sequence.nextval, Emplacement, NumS
    FROM GILLES_HUBERT.tp4_buvettes;
```

This assumes that a sequence is defined for the table -- I don't know if that is actually the case.